# Grandchild process has PID 1 in C

Tags: c, process

I am trying to pass input from parent to child and then from child to grandchild with pipes. After that, the grandchild sends the result to the parent back and the parent will kill both processes.

I can do data passing with pipes but I guess I cannot kill processes because PID of the grandchild is seen as 1 by the parent.

Here is my code:

```
int main(){

    if (pipe(fd) == -1) {
        fprintf(stderr,"Pipe failed fd");
        return 1;
    }

    if (pipe(sd) == -1) {
        fprintf(stderr,"Pipe failed sd");
        return 1;
    }

    if (pipe(td) == -1) {
        fprintf(stderr,"Pipe failed sd");
        return 1;
    }

    printf("Enter a number: ");
    scanf("%s", write_msg);

    pid_child = fork();


    if (pid_child < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Fork failed child");
        return 1;
    }

    if(pid_child > 0){ // parent

        //pass data to child

        close(fd[READ_END]);
        write(fd[WRITE_END], write_msg, strlen(write_msg)+1);
        close(fd[WRITE_END]);


        wait(NULL);

        close(td[WRITE_END]);
        read(td[READ_END], read_msg_parent, strlen(read_msg_parent)+1);
        printf("final output is: %s\n", read_msg_parent);
        fflush(stdout);
        close(td[READ_END]);


        kill(pid_child);
        printf("killed child with pid: %d\n" , pid_child);

        kill(pid_grandc);
        printf("killed grandchild with pid: %d\n" , pid_grandc);

    } else { // child + grandchild

        pid_grandc = fork();


        if (pid_grandc < 0) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Fork failed grand child");
            return 1;
        }

        if(pid_grandc > 0){ // child

            // get data from parent

            close(fd[WRITE_END]);
            read(fd[READ_END], read_msg_child, BUFFER_SIZE);
            sscanf(read_msg_child, "%d", &x);
            printf("Child: input %d and output %d\n", x, x*2);
            fflush(stdout);
            close(fd[READ_END]);



            // pass data to grandchild

            close(sd[READ_END]);
            x *= 2;
            sprintf(write_msg2, "%d", x);
            write(sd[WRITE_END], write_msg2, strlen(write_msg2)+1);
            close(sd[WRITE_END]);

            wait(NULL);
            exit(0);

        } else { // grandchild

            // get data from child

            close(sd[WRITE_END]);
            read(sd[READ_END], read_msg_grandchild, strlen(read_msg_grandchild)+1);
            close(sd[READ_END]);

            sscanf(read_msg_grandchild, "%d", &z);
            printf("Grandchild: input %d, output: %d\n",z, z*2);
            fflush(stdout);
            z *= 2;

            // pass data to child back
            close(td[READ_END]);
            sprintf(write_msg3, "%d",z);
            write(td[WRITE_END], write_msg3, strlen(write_msg3) + 1);
            close(td[WRITE_END]);

            exit(0);

        }

    }
    return 0;
}
```

And the sample output is:

```
> Enter a number: 12 
> Child: input 12 and output 24 
> Grandchild: input 24,output: 48 
> final output is: 48 
> killed child with pid: 7321 
> killed grandchild with pid: 1
```

Comment: A lot of things about the structure of the code are weird to me, but the main issue seems to be that you're killing `pid_grandc` before it's been initialized.

Comment: I am new about C programming, but I thought wait(NULL) handles it.

Comment: when is it initialized exactly and how can I fix it?

Comment: I don't understand. How is `pid_grandc` declared? Are you assuming it should have any meaningfull value? It looks uninitiliazed - you don't assign to `pid_grandc` anywhere.

Comment: You never set pid_grandc in the parent.  You set it in the child, but that has no effect on the parent.  To get the grandchild's pid in the parent, you'll need to send it from the child to the parent somehow...

Comment: Oh, you meant it is declared in the child process but not in the parent if we draw a process tree. Is there any way to kill the grandchild process without passing its pid?

Comment: The parent process cannot know the PID of its child’s child.  The child could tell its parent; the grandchild could its grandparent.  But the info has to be passed explicitly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code, since the child is the one that creates grandchild process, the parent doesn't know the grandchild's pid.

I think you can pass the grandchild's pid by using an extra pipe.

after you check:

```
    if(pid_grandc > 0){ // child
    passGrandchildPid(newpipename, pid_grandc);  // function to write pid to pipe

    }
    // ...


void passGrandchildPid(int newpipename[2], int pid_grandc){
        int pid = grand_child_pid;
         close(newpipename[0]);          /* Close unused read end */
             write(newpipename[1], &pid , sizeof(pid));
             close(newpipename[1]);
             fflush(stdout);
    }
```

Then in the parent process, you can read the grandchild's process id from this new pipe and kill it.